# Minio Azure Gateway and .Net SDK

Tags: .net, azure, azure-blob-storage, minio

We have been using Azure Blob Storage as our primary storage provider in our applications. Lately we wanted to use Minio on our Kubernetes cluster and also connect it to Azure and also to the other supported storages.

The purpose behind this as you can guess is to have a unified API in our code. My question is how can I connect an existing Minio Server on Kubernetes with its Azure Gateway to our existing Azure Storage account and then reach it via Minio .NET SDK? Is there any way to do this?

Answer from Minio: https://twitter.com/abperiasamy/status/990842554101870592

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually possible to connect Minio with Azure blob storage and S3 as well. 
You can use their API using the following code:

From Docker:

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 --name azure-s3 -e "MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=azureaccountname" -e "MINIO_SECRET_KEY=azureaccountkey" minio/minio gateway azure
```

Using Binary:

```
export MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=azureaccountname
export MINIO_SECRET_KEY=azureaccountkey
minio gateway azure
```

More info can be found here: **https://www.minio.io/azure.html**

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I know I can connect like this, but is there a way to integrate this into our actual Kubernetes deployment or do I have to deploy it separately?

Comment: fortunately Minio did not share any documentation about the steps you're asking for. The closest i could get to is https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/storage/minio , You could attempt to add the Azure integration during the deployment step, but you'd still have to make code changes separately still perhaps.

Comment: It's a bit late but the solution I found was creating multiple Minio instances, one for Azure Storage (as a gateway) and another one for Minio Server. So basically I'll have just two different connection string but will be able to use the same client in my code. It was also an official recommendation from Minio: https://twitter.com/abperiasamy/status/990842554101870592